# Android use REAL unix time

Tags: java, android, unix, time, local

I want to get the real unix time stamp. So even in case you change the time of your device manually into the future, I get the real time. I've already searched for it here and found `System.CurrentTimeMillis` but it didn't solve my problem.

If it's not possible to do it, how could I check it with a time server?

Comment: Wow Very fast answer. I will have a look on it Thx :)

Answer (score 1):

By using this SntpClient class

```
class GetNTPAsynctask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
   SntpClient sntpClient = new SntpClient();
   @Override
   protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
       boolean success = false;
       try {
            success = sntpClient.requestTime("pool.ntp.org", 30000);
       }
       catch (Exception e) {
           Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground: Exception" + e.getMessage());
           success = false;
       }
       return success;
   }

   @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
       super.onPostExecute(aBoolean);

       if(aBoolean) {
           long currentTimeMiliseconds = sntpClient.getNtpTime();
           // use it...
       }
       else {
           Toast.makeText(context, "Connection to device not possible.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
   }
 }
```

just call this `AsyncTask`

```
GetNTPAsynctask asyncTask = new GetNTPAsynctask();
asyncTask.execute();
```

Use this sntpclient class

```
import android.net.TrafficStats;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.util.Log;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class SntpClient {
private static final String TAG = "SntpClient";
private static final boolean DBG = true;
private static final int REFERENCE_TIME_OFFSET = 16;
private static final int ORIGINATE_TIME_OFFSET = 24;
private static final int RECEIVE_TIME_OFFSET = 32;
private static final int TRANSMIT_TIME_OFFSET = 40;
private static final int NTP_PACKET_SIZE = 48;
private static final int NTP_PORT = 123;
private static final int NTP_MODE_CLIENT = 3;
private static final int NTP_MODE_SERVER = 4;
private static final int NTP_MODE_BROADCAST = 5;
private static final int NTP_VERSION = 3;
private static final int NTP_LEAP_NOSYNC = 3;
private static final int NTP_STRATUM_DEATH = 0;
private static final int NTP_STRATUM_MAX = 15;
// Number of seconds between Jan 1, 1900 and Jan 1, 1970
// 70 years plus 17 leap days
private static final long OFFSET_1900_TO_1970 = ((365L * 70L) + 17L) * 24L * 60L * 60L;
// system time computed from NTP server response
private long mNtpTime;
// value of SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() corresponding to mNtpTime
private long mNtpTimeReference;
// round trip time in milliseconds
private long mRoundTripTime;
private static class InvalidServerReplyException extends Exception {
    public InvalidServerReplyException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
 /**
 * Sends an SNTP request to the given host and processes the response.
 *
 * @param host host name of the server.
 * @param timeout network timeout in milliseconds.
 * @return true if the transaction was successful.
 */
public boolean requestTime(String host, int timeout) {
    InetAddress address = null;
    try {
        address = InetAddress.getByName(host);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (DBG) Log.d(TAG, "request time failed: " + e);
        return false;
    }
    return requestTime(address, NTP_PORT, timeout);
}
public boolean requestTime(InetAddress address, int port, int timeout) {
    DatagramSocket socket = null;
    try {
        socket = new DatagramSocket();
        socket.setSoTimeout(timeout);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[NTP_PACKET_SIZE];
        DatagramPacket request = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length, address, port);
        // set mode = 3 (client) and version = 3
        // mode is in low 3 bits of first byte
        // version is in bits 3-5 of first byte
        buffer[0] = (byte) (NTP_MODE_CLIENT | (NTP_VERSION << 3));
        // get current time and write it to the request packet
        final long requestTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        final long requestTicks = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
        writeTimeStamp(buffer, TRANSMIT_TIME_OFFSET, requestTime);
        socket.send(request);
        // read the response
        DatagramPacket response = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
        socket.receive(response);
        final long responseTicks = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
        final long responseTime = requestTime + (responseTicks - requestTicks);
        // extract the results
        final byte leap = (byte) ((buffer[0] >> 6) & 0x3);
        final byte mode = (byte) (buffer[0] & 0x7);
        final int stratum = (int) (buffer[1] & 0xff);
        final long originateTime = readTimeStamp(buffer, ORIGINATE_TIME_OFFSET);
        final long receiveTime = readTimeStamp(buffer, RECEIVE_TIME_OFFSET);
        final long transmitTime = readTimeStamp(buffer, TRANSMIT_TIME_OFFSET);
        /* do sanity check according to RFC */
        // TODO: validate originateTime == requestTime.
        checkValidServerReply(leap, mode, stratum, transmitTime);
        long roundTripTime = responseTicks - requestTicks - (transmitTime - receiveTime);
        // receiveTime = originateTime + transit + skew
        // responseTime = transmitTime + transit - skew
        // clockOffset = ((receiveTime - originateTime) + (transmitTime - responseTime))/2
        //             = ((originateTime + transit + skew - originateTime) +
        //                (transmitTime - (transmitTime + transit - skew)))/2
        //             = ((transit + skew) + (transmitTime - transmitTime - transit + skew))/2
        //             = (transit + skew - transit + skew)/2
        //             = (2 * skew)/2 = skew
        long clockOffset = ((receiveTime - originateTime) + (transmitTime - responseTime))/2;
        if (DBG) {
            Log.d(TAG, "round trip: " + roundTripTime + "ms, " +
                    "clock offset: " + clockOffset + "ms");
        }
        // save our results - use the times on this side of the network latency
        // (response rather than request time)
        mNtpTime = responseTime + clockOffset;
        mNtpTimeReference = responseTicks;
        mRoundTripTime = roundTripTime;
    } catch (Exception e) {

        if (DBG) Log.d(TAG, "request time failed: " + e);
        return false;
    } finally {
        if (socket != null) {
            socket.close();
        }
    }
    return true;
}
/**
 * Returns the time computed from the NTP transaction.
 *
 * @return time value computed from NTP server response.
 */
public long getNtpTime() {
    return mNtpTime;
}
/**
 * Returns the reference clock value (value of SystemClock.elapsedRealtime())
 * corresponding to the NTP time.
 *
 * @return reference clock corresponding to the NTP time.
 */
public long getNtpTimeReference() {
    return mNtpTimeReference;
}
/**
 * Returns the round trip time of the NTP transaction
 *
 * @return round trip time in milliseconds.
 */
public long getRoundTripTime() {
    return mRoundTripTime;
}
private static void checkValidServerReply(
        byte leap, byte mode, int stratum, long transmitTime)
        throws InvalidServerReplyException {
    if (leap == NTP_LEAP_NOSYNC) {
        throw new InvalidServerReplyException("unsynchronized server");
    }
    if ((mode != NTP_MODE_SERVER) && (mode != NTP_MODE_BROADCAST)) {
        throw new InvalidServerReplyException("untrusted mode: " + mode);
    }
    if ((stratum == NTP_STRATUM_DEATH) || (stratum > NTP_STRATUM_MAX)) {
        throw new InvalidServerReplyException("untrusted stratum: " + stratum);
    }
    if (transmitTime == 0) {
        throw new InvalidServerReplyException("zero transmitTime");
    }
}
/**
 * Reads an unsigned 32 bit big endian number from the given offset in the buffer.
 */
private long read32(byte[] buffer, int offset) {
    byte b0 = buffer[offset];
    byte b1 = buffer[offset+1];
    byte b2 = buffer[offset+2];
    byte b3 = buffer[offset+3];
    // convert signed bytes to unsigned values
    int i0 = ((b0 & 0x80) == 0x80 ? (b0 & 0x7F) + 0x80 : b0);
    int i1 = ((b1 & 0x80) == 0x80 ? (b1 & 0x7F) + 0x80 : b1);
    int i2 = ((b2 & 0x80) == 0x80 ? (b2 & 0x7F) + 0x80 : b2);
    int i3 = ((b3 & 0x80) == 0x80 ? (b3 & 0x7F) + 0x80 : b3);
    return ((long)i0 << 24) + ((long)i1 << 16) + ((long)i2 << 8) + (long)i3;
}
/**
 * Reads the NTP time stamp at the given offset in the buffer and returns
 * it as a system time (milliseconds since January 1, 1970).
 */
private long readTimeStamp(byte[] buffer, int offset) {
    long seconds = read32(buffer, offset);
    long fraction = read32(buffer, offset + 4);
    // Special case: zero means zero.
    if (seconds == 0 && fraction == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ((seconds - OFFSET_1900_TO_1970) * 1000) + ((fraction * 1000L) / 0x100000000L);
}
/**
 * Writes system time (milliseconds since January 1, 1970) as an NTP time stamp
 * at the given offset in the buffer.
 */
private void writeTimeStamp(byte[] buffer, int offset, long time) {
    // Special case: zero means zero.
    if (time == 0) {
        Arrays.fill(buffer, offset, offset + 8, (byte) 0x00);
        return;
    }
    long seconds = time / 1000L;
    long milliseconds = time - seconds * 1000L;
    seconds += OFFSET_1900_TO_1970;
    // write seconds in big endian format
    buffer[offset++] = (byte)(seconds >> 24);
    buffer[offset++] = (byte)(seconds >> 16);
    buffer[offset++] = (byte)(seconds >> 8);
    buffer[offset++] = (byte)(seconds >> 0);
    long fraction = milliseconds * 0x100000000L / 1000L;
    // write fraction in big endian format
    buffer[offset++] = (byte)(fraction >> 24);
    buffer[offset++] = (byte)(fraction >> 16);
    buffer[offset++] = (byte)(fraction >> 8);
    // low order bits should be random data
    buffer[offset++] = (byte)(Math.random() * 255.0);
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Omer Hayat i already using this code. Its working.

Comment: @Tester if this solve your problem please accept my answer.

Comment: @Omer Hayat At first thank you very much for your fast response. I am still having a problem with this class: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/net/SntpClient.java       http://prntscr.com/gw1ran   Would be nice if you could help me with this :) And thank you again for your effort.

Comment: @Tester what problem?

Comment: @OmarHayat Again thank you for the fast reply :) The problem is that TrafficStats.TAG_SYSTEM_NTP in the Sntp Client is not getting initialized. 
     https://prnt.sc/gw1ran

Comment: @Tester I edit code with SntpClient class please use that class

Comment: @Tester is this answer helpful for you?

Comment: @OmarHayat Thank you a lot! The code itself is working fine but I don't get the time somethow :/ I've waited for about 3 mins without anything appearing. I used the currentTimeMiliseconds variable

Comment: @Tester this is working code check your internet connection  and check success.

Comment: @OmarHayat Hi this is my code: https://mega.nz/#F!ogsS2RII!Za_Wk0rnRElYBK_8sDIPpw  Would be really kind from you to have a look on to it and see why it doesn't work with me. Thank you :)